# Get last 6 months but return 7 months records?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range, postgresql-13

I'm trying to get rows for the last 6 months from a table. Here's the code:

```
select "datetime" 
from "someTable" 
where "datetime" >= '2021-06-09 16:00:00'::timestamp - interval '6 months'
and   "datetime" <= '2021-06-09 16:00:00'::timestamp
group by "datetime"
```

**Result:**

```
2020-12-09 16:00:00
...
2021-06-09 16:00:00
```

**Expected Result:**

```
2021-01-09 16:00:00
...
2021-06-09 16:00:00
```

Can anyone explain why using `- interval '6 months'` returns 7 months' records? I've tried not to use `interval` but `between`, the result being the same. I also don't want to use `5 months` instead of `6 months` to get the expected result.

Comment: The interval between 2020-12-09 and 2021-06-09 is 6 months, the first month is 2020-12-09 to 2021-01-09 and the sixth month is 2021-05-09 to 2021-06-09. So if you want the records between 2021-01-09 to 2021-06-09, then it is indeed 5 months interval.

Comment: @FuXiangShu Thank you for your comment! So which means if i want to get records from 2021-01-09 to 2021-06-09 should use 5 months interval, or is there any other way to SQL to get what i expected?

Comment: Yes because 2021-01-09 to 2021-06-09 is 5 months. Is there any reason that you must use `6 months` instead of `5 months`? Because if it is indeed 5 months of records that you want, the I suggest you use `5 months` in the code to make it clearer.

Comment: I get it now! Thank you for your explanation @FuXiangShu

Comment: What i trying to do is to get last 6 months record, so i use `- interval 6 months`, then the result of the sixth month is from 2021-05-09 TO 2021-06-09. But what i thought is the sixth month is start from 2021-06-01 TO 2021-06-09, I make a mistake on understanding how to calculate `1 month`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `>` instead of `>=` to exclude the lower bound:

```
where datetime > timestamp '2021-06-09 16:00:00' - interval '6 months'
```

Then you should get 6 rows as desired.